# Maximize $b-\sqrt{x'Qx}$

Tags: optimization, self-learning

What kind of optimization problem is the maximization of $b-\sqrt{x'Qx}$ over $x$, where $b\in \mathbb{R}$, $x$ is a $n \times 1$ matrix and Q an $n \times n $ matrix, and given some $=$ and $\leq$ constraints. Is it a NLP or quadratic programming problem?

Comment: Assuming you maximize over $x$, this is a second order cone optimization problem if $Q$ is positive semidefinite, and a nonconvex NLP otherwise.

Comment: You can recast the problem as $\{\min \|\mathbf{x}\|_Q - b\}$. Then if $Q$ is PSD and the constraints are also convex you have a simple convex program that can be efficiently solved using various techniques. The relation is NLP -> convex program -> quadratic program

Comment: Actually it feels like the problem is ill defined if $Q$ is not positive semidefinite, since it can be that $x^TQx<0$. Now if $Q$ is positive semidefinite, maximization will always give $+\infty$ (or $0$ if all eigen values of $Q$ are $0$), indeed if there is $x$ such that $x^T Q x >0$, then you can take $ax$ to multiply this by $a^2$ with $a$ as big as you want.